# try/catch causes <anonymous> in stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

If I have a `try/catch` in one of my calls and it causes the stack to "reset" at that point.  I have 2 questions because of this -

1) Why does this happen?  I imagine it's something with how the v8 engine works but it would be interesting to know why.

2) Is there a good solution to use `async/await` and still keep the entire stack trace?  Right now I am putting a `try/catch` all the way down the function call chain and rolling an error into a new error all the way back out (using VError).

The following code gives the stack trace I would expect

```
async function one() {
  throw new Error("blah");
}

async function two() {
  await one();
}

async function three() {
  await two();
}

async function four() {
  try {
    await three();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

four();
```

stack trace

```
Error: blah
  at one (/dev/async-stack/correct-stack.js:2:9)
  at two (/dev/async-stack/correct-stack.js:6:9)
  at three (/dev/async-stack/correct-stack.js:10:9)
  at four (/dev/async-stack/correct-stack.js:15:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/dev/async-stack/correct-stack.js:21:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Putting in a `try/catch` in the middle causes a stack trace to start where the last `try/catch` was.

```
async function one() {
  throw new Error("blah");
}

async function breaker() {
  return true;
}

async function stack() {
  try {
    await breaker();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

async function two() {
  await stack(); // <-- this call 
  await one();
}

async function three() {
  await two();
}

async function four() {
  try {
    await three();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

four();
```

stack trace

```
Error: blah
  at one (/dev/async-stack/broken-stack.js:2:9)
  at two (/dev/async-stack/broken-stack.js:19:9)
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
  at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Comment: Probably because that's how it is desugared to `then` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how `async`/`await` syntax desugars. For your first snippet, it's like<sup>1</sup>

```
function one() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error("blah"));
}

function two() {
  return one().then(() => {});
}

function three() {
  return two().then(() => {});
}

function four() {
  return three().then(() => {}).catch(e => { console.log(e); });
}

four();
```

while your second snippet works like<sup>1</sup>

```
function one() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error("blah"));
}

function breaker() {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

function stack() {
  return breaker().then(() => {}).catch(error => { throw error; });
}

function two() {
  return stack().then(() => {
//                    ^^^^^^^ this anonymous function
    return one().then(() => {});
  })
}

function three() {
  return two().then(() => {});
}

function four() {
  return three().then(() => {}).catch(e => { console.log(e); });
}

four();
```

As you can see, `one()` is indeed called from inside an anonymous `then` callback. It actually doesn't have anything to do with `try`/`catch` as your title suggests, but rather that any `await` precedes the `one()` call.

<sub>1: Ignoring details such as `Promise` constructor calls, which probably use a deferred pattern internally so that they don't show up in the stack traces.
 A more pedantic way would be to write `function() { var _resolve, _reject,
 _promise = new Promise((res, rej) => { _resolve = res; _reject = rej; }); try { /* function body */ _resolve(_return_value); } catch(e) { _reject(e); } return _promise; }`</sub>

Comment: Bergi: can I know why your both snippet shows following output in repl.it 
=> Promise { <pending> }
Error: blah
    at one (evalmachine.<anonymous>:2:25)
    at stack.then (evalmachine.<anonymous>:16:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)

Comment: @Dipakchavda I cannot reproduce. If I try at repl.it (with nodejs), I do get that output only for the second snippet not the first.

Comment: this is output of first snippet.
Error: blah
    at one (evalmachine.<anonymous>:2:25)
    at two (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6:10)
    at three (evalmachine.<anonymous>:10:10)
    at four (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:10)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:17:1
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:74:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:182:6)
    at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:137:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:120:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
=> Promise { <pending> }

Comment: Please review same link: https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-nodejs-online#&togetherjs=1hkwMe0Er3

Comment: I found two times an error so I gave downvote. You give me the satisfactory answer or resolution.

Comment: Great explanation @Bergi.  Do you know of a way to still get the entire stack trace or do you have to bubble up the error all the way?

Comment: @Dipakchavda You must have misunderstood the question and the answer. It's all centered around the idea of creating an error and logging it to get a stack trace. So if you see that error message, everything works as expected, it's not a reason to downvote but rather the first step in understanding the difference.

Comment: @VtoCorleone I think the V8 team are working on getting the stack traces of `async function`s right, so just sit and wait. Alternatively you could transpile the syntax to Bluebird coroutines, and enable [Bluebirds long stack traces](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/features.html#long-stack-traces) which append "from previous event XY" lines. (I guess there are other promise libraries with this feature but Bluebird is the most prominent one).

Comment: I've read about the bluebird solution but I think I'll stick with my current implementation.  Thanks again for the explanation.  Voted this as the correct answer.

Comment: Bergi I understood the question well. There is not an issue of bias even. I revert my down vote by the way.

Comment: @Dipakchavda I don't understand what your comments are about then. It is expected that the snippets in my answer log the same (similar) error stack traces as the snippets in the question. Is there any problem left?